# Amazon - install a complete server on EBS

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

is it possible to install a full working OS with a webserver, db, and all needed stuff on an EBS storage?

If so, would I immediatly gain benefits by mounting this EBS on a better instance?

Otherwise (if I cannot install a complete image, or if you don't think it's reasonable) can I install the software so that I only need to mount the EBS on a new instance to have it working?

I purchased a Medium Reserved Instance, but when there will be the need to get a better instance I'd like to move the whole db/website, I'd simply buy a better instance and then attach the EBS. Is it possibile? I'm imaging about it like an hard drive that would be mounted on a better server. Of course, more RAM would allow me to increase caching limits, and that's ok, but I don't want to reinstall anything (the main website is a magentocommerce and it's pretty painful to move it).

P.S. is the Standard EBS (100 IOPS) valid or do I need to choose a Provisioned IOPS (up to 1000 IOPS)?

Comment: Have you thought of moving the database to RDS?

Answer (score 2):

You can stop an EBS instance and change its attributes. So, you can stop it and change the instance type and start it again with the new instance type.
[Modifying Attributes of a Stopped Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_ChangingAttributesWhileInstanceStopped.html)

Comment: Although it is possible to modify the instance type, be aware that your current reservation for a Medium instance will no longer be valid if you upgrade to a Large instance for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can switch instance types without loosing data if you have EBS - but you will have to pay for at the un-reserved pricing rate on the large instance. (so you loose your investment in the reserved medium)

I recommend setting up a CDN, it will keep most of the traffic off your webserver and make your entire site run faster.

More tips - including CDN setup info - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/understanding-magento-scalability-and-performance

Comment: Thanks, I'll also setup CloudFront.
Should I only keep the DB or also the webserver root on ebs in your opinion? Or also some other files?